Chaining Problem - PlanningListVariable dynamic duration
I am currently using a @PlanningListVariable with @PreviousElementShadowVariable and @NextElementShadowVariable which is working fine, however I would like timefold to calculate the duration (each customer requires X amount of time per week across Y number of visits, this needs to be allocated across the staff) however when I add a @PlanningVariable onto the class with @PreviousElementShadowVariable and @NextElementShadowVariable it doesn't compile and says "has no entityClass configured and because there are multiple in the entityClassSet it cannot be deduced automatically".
Is what i'm doing not possible in this way? and would need to go to the CHAINED variable and VariableListener route?

List variable doesn't support co-habitation with any other genuine planning variable - that's the reason why you're seeing the error. But that's not a problem, because you don't actually want a genuine planning variable for this - you want a cascading update shadow variable.

I have looked at the cascading update shadow variables which worked great for things that relied on the previous items e.g Start Time however Duration is to be changed / calculated by Timefold and isn't based on previous items, which is why I was going to use a PlanningVariable for this, or have I missed interrupted the cascading update shadow variable?

Planning variable is something changed by the solver, not computed by user code. If cascading variable doesn't work for you, write a variable listener to make any updates you please.

Yeah planning variable is what I was going for so the solver can determine the right duration, pretty much each customer has X amount of hours per week split between Y amount of visits, so I have got it so timefold would try and get to the most optimal visit length being X/Y but this isn't always possible, I currently have a partially working solution using the AnchorShadowVariable and the CHAINED method with planningvariables, would you still recommend to use the List variables instead?

Chained variables are a legacy model which is gradually being replaced by the list variable. Some features of chained are not yet available in list, but for the use case as you described it, I don't think it should matter.

How could I do it with the ListVariable instead of using the PlanningVariable for the Duration?

Do not use a planning variable for duration. It is not a planning variable - it is a shadow variable. Use a variable listener to update that shadow variable. Once you do it like this, you can do the rest with a list variable, because you no longer need two planning variables.

but with a shadow variable and variable listener I would only be able to set it to a value rather than having a "target" value wouldn't I?
